# ACRA Report Fields -Can't add more report fields

Tags: android, acra

By default ACRA is only populating two fields basically a memory dump and a stacktrace. 
I am trying to get ACRA to return fields like APP_VERSION, ANDROID_VERSION, PHONE_MODEL, but in latest version of ACRA i'm  not finding ReportField.*    Below is what is shown in the documentation but its not compiling for me.

```
 import static ReportField.*;   
 @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        customReportContent = { APP_VERSION, ANDROID_VERSION, PHONE_MODEL, CUSTOM_DATA,   STACK_TRACE, LOGCAT },                
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text 
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
```

Answer (score 1):

org.acra.ReportField does exist in the acra jar file.  However in Android 4.0, JDK 1.6

the line:

import static ReportField.*; does not compile.

It should be:

```
 import static org.acra.ReportField.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats all fields from acra version 4.4.0
BUT REMEMBER!! 90% from erros on confg acra are on google docs form

Try this:

```
import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportField;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", customReportContent = {ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA,
        ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT, ReportField.AVAILABLE_MEM_SIZE, ReportField.REPORT_ID, ReportField.APPLICATION_LOG, ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME, ReportField.FILE_PATH,
        ReportField.BUILD, ReportField.BRAND, ReportField.PRODUCT, ReportField.TOTAL_MEM_SIZE, ReportField.INITIAL_CONFIGURATION, ReportField.CRASH_CONFIGURATION, ReportField.DISPLAY,
        ReportField.USER_COMMENT, ReportField.USER_APP_START_DATE, ReportField.USER_CRASH_DATE, ReportField.DUMPSYS_MEMINFO, ReportField.EVENTSLOG, ReportField.RADIOLOG, ReportField.IS_SILENT,
        ReportField.DEVICE_ID, ReportField.INSTALLATION_ID, ReportField.DEVICE_FEATURES, ReportField.ENVIRONMENT, ReportField.SETTINGS_SYSTEM, ReportField.SETTINGS_SECURE,
        ReportField.SHARED_PREFERENCES, ReportField.MEDIA_CODEC_LIST, ReportField.THREAD_DETAILS})
public class XYZApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        ACRA.init(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```